# Contact SelectOptions is blank

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am going through an old version of Jason Ouellette's book, and, I am on the chapter where I create a `VisualForce Page` that starts off with a list of `Contact` and `Skill` records.  I am just trying to start off with getting the list of contacts, but, there is nothing being populated in the `selectList`, and I don't know why.

Here is the VisualForce markup:

```
<apex:page controller="basicSkillsMatrixController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Services Manager" subtitle="Skills Matrix" />
      <apex:pageMessages />
  <apex:form id="form">
    <apex:OutputLabel value="Contact:" for="selectedContactId"/>
      <apex:selectList id="selectedContactId" title="Contact" value="{!selectedContactId}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!contactOptions}" />  
      </apex:selectList>
      <apex:commandbutton action="{!refresh}" value="Go" />

  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

and here is the Controller code:

```
public class basicSkillsMatrixController {

    public PageReference refresh() {
        //if (selectedContactId == null) {
        //  addError('Select A Contact');
          return null;
        //}
    }


    public String contactOptions { get; set; }

    public String selectedContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact selectedContact { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectOption> getContactOptions() {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('','-- Select Contact --'));
      List<Contact> contacts = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact ORDER BY LastName ];
      for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(contact.Id, contact.Name));
      }
      return options;
    }
}
```

I assume I am missing something simple. I am also a little confused by the `getContactOptions` function, which is getting `"{!contactOptions}"`, but, there is no actual variable for `contactOptions`, so, is it implied that for the `contactOptions` are retreived by creating a function, and adding get as a prefix to the variable, ie `getContactOptions`?

Comment: When you say it's blank, do you mean that the list includes no `Contact` records and also doesn't have the `-- Select Contact --` entry that you're adding first? Or does it have the `-- Select Contact --` and just no Contacts?

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks good. There's a potential for a naming conflict as you've got both a member variable and a method for `contactOptions`.

I presume you've actually *got* Contact records in the system to show in the list.

> getContactOptions function, which is getting "{!contactOptions}", but, there is no actual variable for contactOptions, so, is it implied that for the contactOptions are retreived by creating a function, and adding get as a prefix to the variable, ie getContactOptions?

Yes.

`{!contactOptions}` will bind to either example below, but you shouldn't use both mechanisms. The shorthand notation of `contactOptions { get; set; }` is the same as using the methods `getcontactOptions()` and `setcontactOptions()`.

```
// page controllers, unless in very specific situations
// should run using the 'with sharing' keywords
public with sharing class basicSkillsMatrixController {

    public PageReference refresh() {
        //if (selectedContactId == null) {
        //  addError('Select A Contact');
          return null;
        //}
    }

    // this is going to cause a problem as it 
    // "conflicts" with the getContactOptions() method below
    // public String contactOptions { get; set; }

    // this member will hold the value chosen in the select list
    public String selectedContactId { get; set; }

    // this isn't used here yet
    public Contact selectedContact { get; private set; }


    public List<SelectOption> getContactOptions() {

      // this is the list that is going to be returned to the page
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

      // adding an entry to the list with an empty value and a 'pick one' style label
      options.add(new SelectOption('','-- Select Contact --'));

      // this query will return EVERY contact you've got access to
      // it should really have a where clause or a LIMIT n added to it at some point
      List<Contact> contacts = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact ORDER BY LastName ];

      // debug, just to see how many contacts we queried
      // this list returned from a querywill never be null
      system.debug('Contact count: ' + contacts.size());

      // loop over the list and add an entry for each one
      for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(contact.Id, contact.Name));
      }

      // return the selectOptions to the control in the page
      return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Mark.  I understand what you are saying, but, when I comment out that one line:

   ` // notes for me - this is going to cause a problem as it 
    // "conflicts" with the getContactOptions() method below
  //   public String contactOptions { get; set; }`

It gives me a compile error:
Error: Compile Error: The property String contactOptions is referenced by Visualforce Page (basicSkillsMatrix) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 12 column 21

Comment: forgive my etiquette, I thought I was supposed to wrap the code in backticks, but, it doesn't look like it works, it stopped letting me edit while I was still trying to figure out why.  Thanks again. @MarkPond

Comment: Nothing shows up when I uncomment the line that you said was causing the problem, just to check things out again, since then it compiles, in reference to the previous question, the -- Select Contact -- part is also absent from the list.  I only have a few contacts up there while I try to get this working.  Thanks